# Not able to call ctor in JNI?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Currently in my application I am using C++(core implementation) and java(services and presentation). Now in my C++ core I am getting an exception, which I am catching in JNI code and creating a throwable object of it, and throwing it to java layer. So that it can be further processed.

For catching exception on jni I am using following code,

```
catch (namespace::MyException& excep) {
    jclass ex = jenv->FindClass("namespace/MyException");
    jmethodID constructor;
    jthrowable object;
    jobject obj;
    if (ex)
    {
            constructor = jenv->GetMethodID(ex, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I;I)V");
            if(!constructor)
            {
                SWIG_JavaThrowException(jenv, SWIG_JavaRuntimeException, (char*) excep.what());
                return $null;
            }

            jstring str = jenv->NewStringUTF(excep.what());
            jstring str2 = jenv->NewStringUTF(excep.GetStackTraceAsString());
            obj = jenv->NewObject(ex, constructor, str, str2,excep.GetCat(),excep.GetCate());

            object = static_cast<jthrowable>(obj);
            jenv->DeleteLocalRef(str);
            jenv->DeleteLocalRef(str2);
            jenv->Throw(object);
    }
    return $null;
}
```

The C++ signature for my MyException Class is

```
MyException(string str1, string str2, int cat1, int cat2);
```

But in my Jni code I am not able to get methodId For MyException CTOR.

Can any one tell me what could have gone wrong in JNI code. What I suspect is that There is some Problem in parameterList in GetMethodId().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have any semicolons between primitives in your signature. It should be like this:

```
(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;II)V
```

Notice the `II`, not `I;I`.

---

**Edit**

You can always run `javap -s <package.name.ClassName>` on your built classes.

Comment: Thanks maba it worked for me. But I have a doubt why this change for primitive types.

Comment: Well the semicolon is to end a class name definition. Imagine a class that is called ASCII. The name signature will have to be terminated somehow; `LASCII;`.

Comment: Can you suggest me a betther place where I could refer to get my problems solved for JNI?

Comment: @Apoorvasahay The JNI Specification, and in this case javap -s. There isn't any point in trying to write native method signatures yourself when the tool will give them to you flawlessly every time.